# Branch.io(React-Native) :: Not getting CLICK branch event on Mixpanel LiveView

Tags: react-native, analytics, branch.io, mixpanel

I am developing a react-native app. I am using Mixpanel as analytics tool. I want to run a campaign to increase users of app and at the same time I want to track the users journey(from click to campaign link to onboarding in app). I integrated Branch.io for this purpose. I created a quick link to run a campaign.

I have following understanding regarding Branch events:

1. **CLICK** : An event that will be recorded when end user tap on a quick link.
2. **INSTALL** :  An event that will be recorded when end user tap on 'install' at playstore or appstore to install app.
3. **OPEN** : An event that will be recorded when end user first time opened app after installation.
4. **REINSTALL** : An event that will be recorded when end user uninstalled and reinstalled app later using same quick link.

After successful completing all steps as per documentation from [here](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/mixpanel). I have few issues :

1. I am getting INSTALL, OPEN and REINSTALL as recorded events on LiveView of Mixpanel but I am not getting CLICK.
2. I am getting INSTALL and OPEN events not in order. Sometime OPEN is showing before INSTALL and sometimes INSTALL before OPEN.
3. As CLICK->INSTALL->OPEN is sequence then why sum of INSTALL and OPEN is more than CLICK?? Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct definition of Branch Events:

`CLICK`: A user-initiated action of tapping on a Branch link or HTML element directly in front of a Branch link

`INSTALL`: This is the first time an app launches for a given IDFA/AAID. Basically the first app open is treated as an Install event.

`OPEN`: A mobile app launch that is not an install (ie all the subsequent app opens post the first time app launch). An "open" ends when an app is backgrounded or closed.

`REINSTALL`: For a particular device with unique identifiers values remaining constant, the Install instance once recorded and attributed cannot be re-attributed as Install since the Install Event would only occur once per device. Any subsequent install instances after the user uninstall the app would
be counted as Re-installs provided the Branch SDK was present within the App Code at both the times (At Install and also Re-install).

Coming back to the issues which you are facing-

1. Branch doesn't send `Clicks` to MixPanel. Please reference [this](https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/mixpanel#what-events-does-branch-send) doc.
2. There is no specific order which is being followed here. Branch Dashboard analytics shows the data as per when the event is recorded.
3. When you check `organic`, it denotes unattributed events. These events are not driven from a Branch Link click, which is one of the reasons you may observe fewer clicks than the sum of Installs + Opens.